# Make rounded corners for nested div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a rounded corners for my responsive table using div but the top part of the div isn't being rounded.

This is how my current preview looks like:
[image]

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/ajt98kqy/

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="coltable">
<div class="col">
    <h4>Name</h4>
    <p>John</p>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>Manager</p>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is rounded corner (top border isn't rounded yet). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inner content is currently overflowing and is visible. You need to add the CSS property `overflow: hidden`.

So it will be like:

```
.coltable {
....
overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this way no matter how many inner items you add it will always be rounded at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You need to round the `h4` element depending on which column it is in. For example:

```
.coltable .col h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .75rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0; // add this to your code
}

.coltable .col:last-child h4 {
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

The values represent each corner, starting from the top left and going around clockwise.

I've targeted the right column by using `last-child` pseudo; if you add an extra 3rd column, it will still work.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajt98kqy/3/

Comment: thanks for the help. however, it has problem with responsiveness. whenever I resize it, the right corner of the table is being cut off

Comment: He's not using a table for layout OR styling.

Comment: Yes, I re-read the post and made a mistake! I've updated the fiddle and sorted it on mobile Kim

Comment: @Rob i mean the "div" table not really <table>

Comment: @KimGary If you have tabular data, use a table and not a div, but his original response was as if you were using `<table>`.

Comment: Hi I can made it works by simply adding overflow:hidden to the outer div. Thanks to @tam! Thanks I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, you can add the class "rounded" to your div.

```
e.g "<div class="coltable rounded">
```

Otherwise you can use the style "border-radius" by doing either of the following.

**Inline styling:**

```
 <div class="coltable" style="border-radius: 5px;">
```

**External Styling:**

*CSS :*

```
.rounded{
border-radius: 5px; // This will round every side of your border.
}
```

*HTML :*

```
<div class="coltable rounded">

Remember if you are using external CSS, you will have to link to your css file in the 
<head> tag of your document.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file/nameofcssfile.css">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. However I can fix the corner issue already just by adding overflow:hidden to my outer div. I appreciate for taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` into `.coltable` class.

Your div `.col` class is overlaping your `.coltable` div.